# Opening a downloaded Word document with VSTO in edit mode by default

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I have a word document, downloaded from the internet, that I would like to perform some operations on in an Application-level Add-In. These operations (document search, unprotecting the document, etc) require that the document be in edit mode when it is opened. Here is some sample code that illustrates my needs:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.DocumentOpen += application_DocumentOpen;
}

private void application_DocumentOpen(Document doc)
{
    if (doc.ProtectionType != WdProtectionType.wdNoProtection)
    {
        // this throws a COMException if the document is opened in read-only mode
        doc.Unprotect("password");
    }

    // ...
}
```

Since this add-in will be distributed to multiple users, I can't assume that the user will set any application properties, such as opening downloaded documents in edit mode by default, so doing it in code would be ideal. Is there some means with VSTO or the interop library to accomplish this, given my constraints? Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:** My application-level add-in was tested as installed on Word 2013, and was created with VS 2013, VSTO 4.0.

A sample document that displays the requisite characteristics [can be found here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4vq8g7lkdqd7ti5/WordPackage.docx?dl=0). The document is protected with `WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyFormFields`, and the password is "password".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Word/VSTO are you using.

I tried this using Word 2013 ( 64-bit ) and VSTO 4.0/Visual Studio 2013 and do not get any Exception in the even handler function "application_DocumentOpen". For both read-only and protected docs.

**EDIT**:
Try to change the view to Print View before unprotecting the document.

```
if (doc.ProtectionType != Word.WdProtectionType.wdNoProtection)
{
doc.ActiveWindow.View.Type = Word.WdViewType.wdPrintView; 
doc.Unprotect("password"); 
}
```

Reference : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/not-available-for-reading-error-on-unprotecting-a/a888701b-d70a-4dbc-a1ec-68b8bad80848

Comment: It shoud be posted as a comment, not answer.

Comment: I am using the same version of Word/VSTO as you are. I believe the issue isn't that the document is protected, but that it _comes from an online source, and is thus considered unsafe_. Here is an example of a similar document that [displays the same characteristics](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4vq8g7lkdqd7ti5/WordPackage.docx?dl=0).

Comment: Try to change the view to Print View before unprotecting the document.   

`code`
if (doc.ProtectionType != Word.WdProtectionType.wdNoProtection)
{
 doc.ActiveWindow.View.Type = Word.WdViewType.wdPrintView;
 doc.Unprotect("password");
}
`code`
[Reference](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/not-available-for-reading-error-on-unprotecting-a/a888701b-d70a-4dbc-a1ec-68b8bad80848)

Comment: This did the trick. Add it as part of your answer and I'll mark it.